# Where can I put this code, containing both Javascript and Ruby, so that it can be used by different views in my RoR app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have some javascript code that is used in a few different pages in my website.

The code changes depending on some parameters, which are set in the Ruby on Rails controller.

For example:

acontroller.rb

```
def aview
    @notes = get_notes
end
```

aview.html.erb (the actual code is much longer)

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
    var <%=note["something"]%> = new Array(); 
<% end %>
```

I want the changeable javascript code to be stored in a central place, able to be used by many different views. Initially I thought to put it in a helper method, using a heredoc, but then the code is just inserted into the view, and the Ruby part of the code is not actually run. I can't just put into a private method in the controller, because there's javascript in it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you put it in a partial? That would allow you to share the code wherever you'd like.